# Java recursion: how to pass a String

Tags: java, recursion

I am examining this code problem:

> Given a dictionary, write a function to flatten it.
>
> Consider the following input/output scenario for better understanding:

```
Input:

{
  'Key1': '1',
  'Key2': {
    'a' : '2',
    'b' : '3',
    'c' : {
      'd' : '3',
      'e' : '1'
      }
    }
}

Output:
{
  'Key1': '1',
  'Key2.a': '2',
  'Key2.b' : '3',
  'Key2.c.d' : '3',
  'Key2.c.e' : '1'
}
```

The accepted solution is below (please note this is pseudocode only).

I want to implement it in Java

```
function flattenDictionary(String initialKey, dictionary, flatDictionary){

  for (key : dictionary.keyset()){
      value = dictionary.get(key)

      if (!isHashMapInstance(value)){ 
          if (initialKey == null || initialKey == "")
              flatDictionary.put(key, value)
          else
              flatDictionary.put(initialKey + "." + key, value)             
      }
      else { 
        if (initialKey == null || initialKey == "")
          flattenDictionary(key, value, flatDictionary)
        else
          //-----> Here we are creating a new String for each recursive call !!!!<----
          flattenDictionary(initialKey + "." + key, value, flatDictionary)
      }
  }
}
```

My doubt is at the the arrow.

We recursively pass to the `flattenDictionary()` method a new String each time by concatenating the `initialKey` with the new `key`that we got from the Map.

**Here we are potentially creating many long Strings!**

Is it possible to avoid creating all those Strings?

I don't think that passing StringBuilder could be a solution, because we would end up with wrong results

Comment: Since Strings are immutable, you always create a new one. Stringbuilder tho uses an internal `char[]` to store the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a StringBuilder if you **undo** your changes after the recursive call. Assuming `initialKey` is now an instance of `StringBuilder`, you can do something like this:

```
int originalLength = initialKey.length()
initialKey.append(".").append(key)

flattenDictionary(initialKey, value, flatDictionary)

initialKey.setLength(originalLength) // undo: delete the appended chars
```